# Did anybody ever use Draal's holographic system after Sheridan's announcement of Babylon-5's independence?

Tags: babylon-5

After [President Morgan Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_Clark) bombed Mars, Captain Sheridan used [Draal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draal)'s holographic system to announce all about the station that [Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5) will join other Earth colonies in declaring independence until President Clark is arrested and rightful government is restored.

**Did anybody use that holographic system later?**

It would be useful for other announcements. It can project images and sounds directly into the B-5 space station orbiting [Epsilon-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_III), so it should also be able to project into spaceships orbiting Epsilon-3. That would be a useful tool to confuse enemy spaceships! I don't think anybody used that holographic ability again. (I am not sure Susan Ivanova used the holographic abilities when she broadcast reports on the atrocities of the Clark regime from the station's War Room. Seems like she used the [Great Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Machine) for signal boosting rather than for projecting holgraphs.)

Comment: I vaguely recall a single throwaway line somewhere early in season 5 (maybe late in season 4?) to the effect that Draal and he Great Machine had gone back into hibernation.

Comment: @JoeL. - I can't find that line myself, but if I stumble on it, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

To be honest, there wasn't a lot of reason to use it during *Severed Dreams* except for [Rule of Drama](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfDrama).  It's not like B5 doesn't have a PA system or emergency "take-shelter" sirens.  It did have the advantage of making everyone who saw it sit up and pay attention, which was probably Sheridan's point, a little bit of awe being useful for getting people to do what they're told.

Regardless, the holograms are not heard from again after that usage.  Draal himself is not heard from again after opening and then sealing the time rift for *War Without End*.  The Great Machine is only ever used again for boosting the signal of the Voice of the Resistance.  With Babylon 5 itself removed some decades later, we can only presume that the machine and Draal have gone quiet and will remain so.

This tends to imply that the point of The Great Machine all along may have only been to enable and manipulate that time rift.  Since we get no other information on it's creation however, that remains speculation.

---

There is [this from the Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/092.html), on a later episode *A View from the Gallery*, possibly explaining the lack of any further involvement from Draal:

> **Why wasn't Draal called?**
>   I don't think Draal wants to be bothered each and every time B5 is in a hassle. He specifically said he wanted to be left alone. Otherwise you also get into a "god in the box" deus ex machina situation where, "Oh, we're in trouble, quick, get Draal." Truth is, if they called him every time they got in trouble, he'd never get ANY sleep.